# Phonegap Android permissions

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, android-permissions

I have a Phonegap app that I'm currently developing and testing for Android. Problem is, when I publish to device, the Android Manifest is full of permission requests that I did not ask for.

I tried adding:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
```

to config.xml but it still doesn't work.

How can I only let "Network permission" only?

Comment: If you use plugins, the permissions needed by the plugins are automatically added to android manifest. Or this may be an issue with phonegap build. Any reason why you aren't building locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the permissions you do not want from the `AndroidManifest`. Those permissions are tagged with `<uses-permission>`. Example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Keep in mind, if you remove permissions that the app needs to function properly, your app will crash.

Also, some external libraries add their own permissions, if they are required. If you do use external libraries, check which permissions that they require. These permissions are defined at compile time and will not be visible in your manifest file.

**Edit**

This is where you find the manifest file in Android Studio

[image: Android Studio Project Structure]

This is where you will find it in Eclipse

[image: Eclipse Project Structure]

Comment: I downloaded the apk and changed .apk to .rar and when open AndroidManifest.xml it shows numbers along file like that 0300 0800 4813 0000 0100 1c00 ac09 0000 sorry iam noob is there a way to get the code in order to open at eclipse ?

Comment: Try [this online decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) if you want to get your hands on the source code from an .apk file.

Comment: yup thx too much i installed program called APK studio then i changed permissions and let network only and it work very fine :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PhoneGap Build (not the command line tools) and some plugin is adding permissions that you know your app does not need, you can remove those permissions by adding lines to your config.xml like:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="delete">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</gap:config-file>
```